# Looping all text fields in a form and converting to decimal/currency

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 12 fields in a form and I'd like to loop through all these 12 text fields and convert the value in those fields to decimal/currency. These 12 (Jan to Dec) fields are numeric (currency US$) only.

And in the end, show in another field:

```
txtPendingBalance.value = TotalValue.text - (Sum(Field1..12))
```

What's the best way doing it? jQuery? pure js?

Comment: What browser? Is jQuery already available?

Comment: Unless you are already using jQuery, you could do this with plain javascript, just need to organize the columns for easy iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do it. "totalbuttonID" should be the ID of the button that is pressed to total the inputs.  The inputs that are being totaled need to have the class addToTotal.

```
$('#totalbuttonID').click(function() {
    val total=0.0;
    $('.addToTotal').each(function(){
         total+=parseFloat($(this).val())
    })
    $('#txtPendingBalance').val(parseFloat($('#TotalValue').val())-total);
})
```

Comment: How do I put a class addToTotal to every input text? many thanks

Comment: Just add `class="addToTotal"` to any of the inputs you want included in the calculation

Answer (score 0):

Check this Example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/uThjm/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
        var $textboxes = $('.a input[type=text]');
        var $balance = $('#totalbalance') ;
        var $pending = $('#pendingbalance');

        var tot = 0;
        $.each($textboxes , function(i){
           tot += parseFloat($(this).val());           
        })
        var pending = parseFloat( parseFloat($balance.val()) - tot );    
        $pending.val( parseFloat(pending).toFixed(2));

    });
});​
```